# How to add comments and work notes in servicenow via REST API

Tags: servicenow-rest-api

I want a api which will post / put the comments and worknotes in servicenow.

I have searched but not any correct API.
If anyone knows then can provide the API details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Table API PATCH method to add a comment or work note to a record. For example, to add a comment to an incident you simply PATCH the incident assigning a new value to the comment field.

This only works for adding comments and work notes. If you attempt to read the value of comments or work_notes using the GET method you will find that the value is always empty. This is because comments and work notes are journal fields. If you have a requirement to read comments via the REST API then you would need to query sys_journal_field, but you cannot use the REST API to write to sys_journal field.